# Regex- remove html tags from string except for tags between backticks?

Tags: regex

I'm sanitizing content in a JSON response and I'm removing HTML tags using the regex replace below, but I'd like to keep any tags that are between backticks ``

```
  // remove html tags
    item = item.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
```

So for example this string:

```
<p>A `<div>` is a block level element</p>
```

Would  be sanitized to:

```
A `<div>` is a block level element
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex flavor support verbs `(*SKIP)` & `(*FAIL)`,  you can use:

```
`<[^>]+>`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<[^>]+>
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/eRSkrI/1)

If it doesn't, use

- Find:

```
`(<[^>]+>`)|<[^>]+>
```

- Replace: `$1`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/eRSkrI/2)